# Disable gitlab two step verification in CLI

Tags: git, gitlab, two-step-verification

I have a situation, `Google Authenticator` generates non-valid codes and my recovery codes are all expired, how can I disable it via command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, we can disable it via `gitlab-rails` :

```
gitlab-rails runner 'User.update_all(otp_required_for_login: false, encrypted_otp_secret: "")'
```

Comment: After running this command I was unable to enable 2FA again, but running `gitlab-rails runner User.update_all(otp_required_for_login: false, encrypted_otp_secret: nil, encrypted_otp_secret_iv: nil, encrypted_otp_secret_salt: nil, otp_backup_codes: nil)` and then `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` fixed it for me.

Comment: @JagjotSingh You are missing a `'` wrapping from `User...` to the end of your command. After adding them it works. Thanks